# ADB over Wi-Fi is extremely slow on one PC, great on another

Tags: android, windows, adb, android-wifi

I'm trying to learn how to develop for Android, and I'd like to be able to test on my device instead of an emulator. The USB port on my phone is getting pretty loose, and I'd rather not mess it up with the scores of hours I'll be using it to test.

I enabled ADB over Wi-Fi on my desktop, and it worked flawlessly. This desktop runs Windows 7 and on my home network.

I then installed Android Studio and enabled ADB over Wi-Fi on my laptop, which runs Windows 10 and on my work network (which has no secondary login and is much faster). It works, but it's EXTREMELY slow. When I hit the "run" button in android studio, I thought it had frozen. But I used adb install, and it worked - but very slowly. It took about 5 minutes to install an apk.

I've done a lot of searching but it seems that everyone seems to dismiss this problem as "a problem with your device" or "a problem with your cable (even though it's over Wi-Fi?)". Or in one case, the solution applied to a Mac.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: did you test the same APK file? the same filesize? mb you had much bigger APK filesize on your work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this was a fluke, but a guide online told me to use the command

```
adb usb
```

before connecting via Wi-Fi. I did this while setting up my desktop, but for my laptop I assumed it was redundant since my phone was already connected via USB. Still, I disconnected adb then went through all the steps:

```
adb usb
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect <ip>
```

And it works perfectly now. Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: check it as answered

Comment: Does this still work for you or do you have any other solutions yet? Executing the line 'adb usb' before connecting to wifi doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I haven't had the problem since then. Hopefully the classic engineers fixes (rebooting etc.) works for you.

Comment: `adb usb` is useless here, you set `adb tcpip 5555` after this anyway, you unplug you device from PC then (no usb connection), so there is only Wi-Fi mode, or you can just use this app (you need root) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb So `adb usb` won't increase installing speed over Wi-Fi.

Comment: also mb you forgot to disconnect USB cable from you device when you tested it, you thought it was fast over ADB Wi-Fi but actually you installed apk over ADB USB

Comment: placebo, placebo, doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a an old post but I found a possible solution that might help.

I had the same problem on my laptop and I felt the speed over Wi-Fi was very slow when I was debugging my app using Android Studio.

The solution I found was to create a hotspot on my laptop and connected my phone to it. After that I configured the adb to connect to the new IP address (adb.exe connect new_ip:5555).

Now the adb connection works seamlessly fast.

Comment: Same here, I don't know if my router is bad or what. Using a hotspot / non crowded network works great.

Answer (score 0):

Switching my computer to use ethernet significantly improved the situation and  having the phone on and unlocked seems to improve things a fair amount as well.

I was having this issue for quite some time and I had given up on actually fixing this. Based on internet speed tests I was getting about 10 Mbps on my desktop with a low-end USB 3.0 WiFi adapter and 80 Mbps on my phone, but when I tried to use adb over WiFi I would get below 1 Mbps. Many times installing an essentially bare app would take over 5 minutes.

More recently I switched my desktop over to ethernet (situation finally permitted me to do so), and the speed on my desktop jumped up to match my phone (80 Mbps), but more importantly the adb transfer speed jumped up to around 80 Mbps as well. This was with the screen off. With some additional testing I determined that having the phone unlocked approximately doubles the speed, as I was seeing over 160 Mbps. Now what used to take minutes usually takes a few seconds.

I suspect that my low-end WiFi adapter may have just been messing things up; some other behavior on the network made me suspect that data was being retransmitted many times due to failure to ACK packets, which would definitely result in much lower speeds. This is probably actionable for very few people.

On the other hand, based on a sample size of one having the phone unlocked could halve the wait time, and this is more actionable. It also makes sense, the phone is likely in a sleep mode when locked. You could use [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) on every activity when the app is in debug mode to try to keep the transfer rates high.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is dangerous, if your device can't connect via usb (like a TV box), and you set "adb usb", you will no longer be able to connect to it via wifi.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Feel sorry by not to follow the  guide.But I dont have enough credits to comment other's answer.