# Android Things - Slow Installation

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-things

I trying to develop a simple application with Android Things and Raspberry Pi 3, the problem is that the installation of the App is very very slow (the size of the apk file is 4 or 5Mb). The network is fine.

I'm using versión 0.5 of Android Things.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you use Mac, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32378608/6950238) solution or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39110048/6950238) for all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, In my case the problem is not the network, something is wrong with SD Card. I change it and everything it's ok.